# Creating an updated and edited nested object from given one (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, recursion, nested-object

I got a schema object that looks like this:

```
const schema = {
social: {
    facebook: 'someValue',
    twitter: {
        department: {
            departmentImage: {
                editable: 'someValue'
            }
         }
      }
   }
};
```

The `editable` property indicates a value that I want to edit,  and may appear in several nested locations in the object.

My approach to edit it is to recursively create a new object who is an exact copy of the original, and populate a new value where I encounter `editable`.
Like this:

```
const formatSchema = (schema, data, formattedSchema = {}) => {
  for (const schemaKey in schema) {
    const firstKey = Object.keys(schema[schemaKey])[0];
            
    if (schema[schemaKey] instanceof Object) {
        formattedSchema[schemaKey] = schema[schemaKey];
        formatschema(schema[schemaKey], data, formattedSchema[schemaKey]);
    }
    if (schema[schemaKey] instanceof Object && firstKey === 'editable') {
       *replacing data logic*
       formattedSchema[schemaKey] = ...*replacingData*;
       formatschema(schema[schemaKey], data, formattedSchema[schemaKey]);
    } else {
        formattedSchema[schemaKey] = schema[schemaKey];
    }
  }
 return formattedSchema;
};
```

But I feel this solution may be inefficient as I create every single bit of the object from scratch and this would happen thousands of times a day.

Is there a way to do it better?

Comment: I don't understand one thing. Do you want to create deep copy or not? Do you ask if this can be done without creating a copy of each nested object? Or do you ask if this can be done faster?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Yes, I do need the deep copy. Just if it can be done faster/more efficiently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recursive immutable `update` that works for any native input type. Don't worry about performance here as it's plenty fast, even if your object has thousands of fields. Let me know how this suits you and I can make a change if it's needed -

```js
function update(t, func) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Object:
      return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(t).map(([k,v]) =>
          [k, func([k, update(v, func)])]
        )
      )
    case Array:
      return t.map((v, k) => func([k, update(v, func)]))
    default:
      return func([null, t])
  }
}

const schema = {
  social: {
    facebook: 'someValue',
    twitter: {
      department: {
        departmentImage: {
            editable: 'someValue'
        }
      },
      someArr: [{ editable: 1 }, { editable: 2 }, { hello: "world" }]
    },
  }
}

console.log(update(schema, ([k,v]) =>
  k == "editable" ? "✅" : v
))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```json
{
  "social": {
    "facebook": "someValue",
    "twitter": {
      "department": {
        "departmentImage": {
          "editable": "✅"
        }
      },
      "someArr": [
        {
          "editable": "✅"
        },
        {
          "editable": "✅"
        },
        {
          "hello": "world"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, working great. Why is it so efficient? I know hash tables (i.e js object) are o(1), but we are mapping arrays here quite a lot. What am I missing?

Comment: javascript objects are not hash tables; all keys are converted to simple string representations. what are “mapping arrays”? javascript arrays, `[…]`, also have O(1) access. the performance of `update` is O(n), and directly proportionate to the size of your input.